# how to convert this simple bruteforce in to multi threading program

Tags: python

I wrote this simple program that gives me the combination of letters and numbers. But this is very slow for large string. So I want to convert this in to multithread program. I am not expert in python. can some body show me some way how to achive this.

```
import string

    def bruteForce(charList,size,nwCombination=[]):
        if not nwCombination:
            nwCombination=charList
        if size==1:
            return nwCombination
        finalCombination=[]
        for x in charList:
            for n in nwCombination:
                cntStr=str(x)+""+str(n)
                finalCombination.append(cntStr)
                if(cntStr=='aadd'):
                    print("string found")
                    print(cntStr)
                    exit(0)
        return bruteForce(charList,size-1,finalCombination)

    allCharlist=string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase
    bruteForce(list(allCharlist)+list(range(0,9)),5)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using the "Mulitprocessing" package ?

Comment: hi @ma3oun, I know about this package but the problem is this that I am not able to get the idea to divide the work of this function in to multi thread and each thread should have unique work to do. So that i can speed up the operation. can you suggest some logic for this?

Comment: I assume that you are suggesting the Multiprocessing package so that i can utilize all the cores of the cpu. I don't know about python multi thread. does it use all core of cpu or single core? Please correct if I am wrong.